# Big Query Import from firestore

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-firestore, database-backups

I am considering BigQuery for a solution and I am not sure of it's feature in regards to Importing (and couldn't find it documented).

I am currently using Firestore and I am performing daily backups.   I would like to take those backups and import them into BigQuery.  This seems very well supported.

My question is whether each import will get a full set of data (essentially duplicating anything that didn't change that day) or can I configure it to import only updated fields?  Do I have to write the full ETL to accomplish this or is it already supported.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Each import in BigQuery will have [all fields by default](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#cloud_firestore_options). You cannot configure it to import only updated fields. However, you can use [CLI or API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#loading_cloud_firestore_export_service_data) to load specific fields by using the [--projection_fields flag](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#cloud_firestore_options) in the CLI or by setting the [projectionFields property](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.load.projectionFields) in the API. Please note that this feature is not available in the BigQuery web UI.

Also note that you would not have a duplicated data in your table as you can either create a new table to store the data, or overwrite an existing table when loading a Cloud Firestore export into BigQuery. It is not possible to add Cloud Firestore export data to an existing table per the current [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-firestore#limitations).

Looking over Cloud Firestore and BigQuery docs, it seems there is no ETL tool that accomplish your needs right now. I have raised a [BigQuery feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/120791449) on Google Issue Tracker. Please add the below information to the ticket so the correct team can be notified about it:

- How this impact your company and daily tasks?

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension for firestore to BigQuery now.
https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-bigquery-export